# Does |W|=2^|V| imply dim V < dim W?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V and W be vector spaces of infinite basis. If $|W|=2^{|V|}$, does it follow that dim V < dim W?

Comment: what do you mean by $|W|$ and $|V|$.

Comment: And if both of them have infinite basis, what do you mean by $dim(V)<dim(W)$.

Comment: I mean the cardinality of W and V. By dim V < dim W, I mean that for instance, V may have a countably infinite basis, and W may have an uncountable one.

Comment: If both vector spaces have infinite basis, then it doesn't make any sense to say $|W|=2^{|V|}$ ! because both are infinity. To speak about cardinality of vector space, the field should be finite!

Comment: Why is that? Can't one say that some vector spaces have cardinality $\aleph_0$, while others have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: If the basis is infinite, then the space itself is infinite. Thus in your notation $N_0=\infty$

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Can't we have $|V|=\aleph_0, |W|=\aleph_1, so |V|<|W|$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be the underlying field with $|K|\geq 2$. Note that $|V|<|W|$ and there is an injection $V\rightarrow W$. Thus $dim(V)\leq dim(W)$. Assume that $dim(V)=dim(W)$. Then there is a bijection between a basis $\mathcal{V}$ of $V$ and a basis $\mathcal{W}$ of $W$. Then there is a bijection between $V$ and $W$, that is contradictory.